# Add nav menu after theme install

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress template and I need to add some menu nav items. 
Does Wordpress has a function that allows me add menu items after the theme install?

Answer (score 0):

Humba, yes there is check this

Defining a Menu
You must define a menu before you can add items to it.

Step 1
Login to the WordPress Dashboard.

From the 'Appearance' menu on the left-hand side of the Dashboard, select the 'Menus'  option to bring up the Menu Editor.

Enter a name for your new menu in the Menu Name box

Click the Create Menu button.

Step 2
Adding Items to a Menu

The Screen Options allow you to choose which items you can use to add to a menu. Certain items, like Posts are hidden by default.

Locate the pane entitled Pages.

Within this pane, select the View All link to bring up a list of all the currently published Pages on your site.

Select the Pages that you want to add by clicking the checkbox next to each Page's title.

Click the Add to Menu button located at the bottom of this pane to add your selection(s) to the menu that you created in the previous step.

Scroll back to the Menu Editor.

Click the Save Menu button.

Ok Humba there is a lot of material out there you can also check this link.
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: I want to add the menu items throw code, not using the User interface.